# ¿Como puedo agregar una cabecera que se repita en todas las paginas?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Tal y como lo dice mi pregunta, utilizo la librería tcpdf y aquí dejo el código:

```html
<?php
 require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
 require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
 require_once('../config.php');

 $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'legal', true, 'UTF-8', false);
 $pdf->SetTitle('PDF Autogenerado en PHP'); //Titlo del pdf
 $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //No se imprime cabecera
 $pdf->setPrintFooter(false); //No se imprime pie de pagina
 $pdf->SetMargins(10, 20, 10, false); //Se define margenes izquierdo, alto, derecho
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 5); //Se define un salto de pagina con un limite de pie de pagina
 $pdf->addPage();
 
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
 
    
 }

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM acarga WHERE bl3 = '$id' ORDER by cod_it ";
 $cosas = $connex->query($sql);
 $html = '';
 $item = 1;
 foreach($cosas as $row){
  $bl = $row['bl3'];
  $item = $row['cod_it'];
  $conductor = $row['noap'];
  $unidad = $row['uni_ca'];
  $placa = $row['pla_ca'];
  $tipopa = $row['tipo_pa'];  
  $registro = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['fecha']));
  $estado = $row['estado'];
  $hora = date('h:i A', strtotime($row['hora']));
  $imagen = $row['ruta_imagen'];
  $destino = $row['dest'];
  $coment = $row['comenta'];
  //$barcode = $row['cosa_codigo_barra'];
  //$barcode = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array($barcode, 'C128', '', '', 72, 25, 0.5, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>false, 'padding'=>2, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>7, 'stretchtext'=>6), 'N'));

  $html .= '
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Caso: </b></td>
      <td>'.$bl.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Item: </b></td>
      <td>'.$item.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Unidad/Camion: </b></td>
      <td>'.$unidad.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Placa del camión: </b></td>
      <td>'.$placa.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Tipo de Mesa/chasis: </b></td>
      <td>'.$tipopa.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Conductor: </b></td>
      <td>'.$conductor.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Fecha: </b></td>
      <td>'.$registro.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Hora: </b></td>
      <td>'.$hora.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Estado: </b></td>
      <td>'.$estado.'<font color="red">*</font> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Destino: </b></td>
      <td>'.$destino.'</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Foto: </b></td>
      <td><img src="../img/'.$imagen.'"width="250px" height="180px"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><b>Comentario: </b></td>
      <td>'.$coment.'</td>
     </tr>
     </table><br><br>
   
     ';
     

  $item = $item+1;
 }

 $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
 $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

 $pdf->lastPage();
 $pdf->output('Reporte.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: Eso se puedo solucionar con css, para dejar en forma estática tu `header` y `footer` para que se repita a alo largo de las paginas de tu documento. Si no te funciona lo que te dejaron abajo como respuesta me avisas y te mando mi código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente no se imprime porque en la configuración estás seteando a "false" la impresión tanto de header como del footer:

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //No se imprime cabecera
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false); //No se imprime pie de pagina
```

Ambas líneas deben ser colocadas como true, es decir, cambia las líneas anteriores por las siguientes:

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true); //Ahora si imprimirá cabecera
$pdf->setPrintFooter(true); //Ahora si imprimirá pie de página
```

También recuerda agregar el contenido de cabecera:

```
$PDF_HEADER_TITLE="Título cabecera"; // Colocas el titulo de tu PDF por ejemplo
$PDF_HEADER_STRING="Descripción de la cabecera"; // Lo que deseas que esté en cabecera
$PDF_HEADER_LOGO="imagen"; 

$this->pdf->SetHeaderData($PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $PDF_HEADER_TITLE, $PDF_HEADER_STRING); // Se establece el header en el documento.
```

**Observación:** `$PDF_HEADER_LOGO` lo puedes omitir si no deseas que la cabecera lleve una imagen, si quieres una imagen entonces deja esta línea tal cual y para que funcione la imagen debe estar dentro de la carpeta images que trae la misma librería por defecto.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: soy un novato en esto, digamos que solo quiero escribir algo básico como "Gracias"

Comment: No te preocupes para eso estamos en esta comunidad para aprender entre todos. Sólo colocas dentro de la función Header "Gracias" y se imprimirá en todas las páginas como cabecera. Me alegra que te ha sido útil.

Comment: intenté así y lo único que me sale es una linea horizontal en top class PDF extends TCPDF { 
    public function Header() { 
    // Aquí información que deseas se muestre en la cabecera bienvenidos
    } 
}

Comment: Quizás no me expliqué bien. He actualizado mi respuesta, por favor prueba y me avisas